# Elasticsearch combining multiple buckets and aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-api

Let's assume we're looking at data that's reasonably simple -- each document in our index has this structure:

```
{
    "Time": "2018-01-01T19:35:00.0000000Z",
    "Country": "Germany",
    "Addr": "security.web.com",
    "FailureCount": 5,
    "SuccessCount": 50
}
```

My question essentially boils down to how I might go about doing something like this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_combining_the_two.html. Specifically, I am trying to perform the same aggregation (query below) on all combinations of `Country` and `Addr`. My current query attempt is below. I aggregate across a 5-minute grain (that is part of my requirements), and so far I have only been able to aggregate based on **one** query.

```
{
"size":0,
"query":{
   "bool":{
      "filter":[
         {
            "range":{
               "Time":{
                  "gte":"1514835300000",
                  "lte":"1514835600000",
                  "format":"epoch_millis"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "query_string":{
               "analyze_wildcard":true,
               "query":"Country:Germany"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
},
"aggs":{
   "2":{
      "date_histogram":{
         "interval":"5m",
         "field":"Time",
         "min_doc_count":0,
         "extended_bounds":{
            "min":"1514835300000",
            "max":"1514835600000"
         },
         "format":"epoch_millis"
      },
      "aggs":{
         "4":{
            "bucket_script":{
               "buckets_path":{
                  "success":"9",
                  "failure":"10"
               },
               "script":"( params.success + params.failure )"
            }
         },
         "9":{
            "sum":{
               "field":"SuccessCount"
            }
         }
         "10":{
            "sum":{
               "field":"FailureCount"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This works, but simply aggregates on all documents that match the bool-filter (over 5-minute buckets). Instead, I wanted to aggregate across **all combinations** of `Country` and `Addr` (over 5-minute buckets).

That is, I would like an aggregation result/metric (as laid out in the `script` in bucket `4`) for all docs that have `"Country": "Germany"` and `"Addr": "security.web.com"`, one for all docs that have `"Country": "United States"` and `"Addr": "security.web.com"`, and so on, for all `Addr`s and all `Country`s. Is this possible in one Elasticsearch request? What might my best option be here?

**Follow-up**

Is this also possible to do not across *all* combinations of `Addr`s and `Country`s, but instead across specific combinations of `Addr`s and `Country`s (that I might lay out in a query)? Or am I overreaching beyond ES's capabilities within one request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this in 1 query, you may just try sub aggregating it 4 times.

```
"aggs": {
    "countries": {
        "terms": {
            "field": country,
            "size": 300
         },
         "aggs": {
             "addrs": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "Addr",
                     "size": 1000
                 },
                 "aggs": {
                     "2": {
                        "date_histogram":.....// your original query
                 }
              }
          }
     }
 }
```

However, I would not recommend doing this on a large amount of data as such deep sub-aggregations would be really slow. If you really need to do this in a single query, create a field which combines country and addr in a single field while indexing and aggregate on it.

If you want specific combinations, just put your combinations inside a [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) and sub-aggregate it with your query.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this got me there! :) Yup, I will prune to specific combinations only, with either a bool filter before aggregations, or using a filters aggregation like you suggested.